# IE11 returns status 0 during Ajax POST operation from an iFrame (XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee2

Tags: ajax, tomcat, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee4, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee2.

In the developer tools Network Panel, I notice that the Result is stated as (Aborted). All other browsers work (chrome, firefox etc.)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

00002ee2 is a timeout error code. If you run Fiddler, do you see the request actually hit the wire? If so, how long does it take for a response to be returned?

Is the request "interesting" in any way (e.g. to an Intranet site, or requiring NTLM authentication, or anything like that)?